# MySQL: How to create a query that executes using array variables on array indexes?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, indexing

I have a query with 3 variables that I run over and over. How can I create a query that will accept arrays of values such that I can run the query once and get all the data in one result? Here is an example:

- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = 3 AND column 2 != 35 AND column 3 > 10`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = 9 AND column 2 != 12 AND column 3 > 293`
- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = 6 AND column 2 != 96 AND column 3 > 39`

I need the query to execute such that the first values (index 0) of each array get run together, then the second values (index 1) of each array get run together and so on. In other words, I want the query to run using the values [based on above example] (3,35,10) then (9,12,293) and so on.

The query needs to be stand alone meaning I need to be able to pass the 3 arrays via $_POST to a remote server that will get directly plugged into the query and executed on the remote server.

Using *IN* and *NOT IN* will not work because those comparison operators do not go in order of array indexes.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I have tried searching many places for solutions and cannot find anything. This type of query might be called something, so maybe that is why I have found nothing.

Comment: What is the exact format of the data in the POST array? Does it have 3 items, each of which is an array? Does it have 9 items? [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) is rarely a good idea; select only the columns you need.

Comment: The arrays contain only integers. Each of the arrays contain identical numbers of indexes. There are approximately 100 indexes in each array, hence the reason why I was looking for a way to have one query (a really long query using UNION as posted below). Also, I don't use SELECT *. I was only trying to make the query shorter in asking my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php, you could build a UNION ALL query as follows:

```
$vals = array(array(3,35,10), array (9,12,293)) //this can be built from $_POST or wherever

$queryArr = array();
foreach ($vals as $arr)
{
 $queryArr[] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = $arr[0] AND column 2 != $arr[1] AND column 3 > $arr[2]";
}

$query = implode(' UNION ALL ', $queryArr);  //note: if you want to do separate queries, rather than a UNION of them, just use $queryArr
```

PS: As outis mentioned in his comments, you should avoid `SELECT *` and specify the fields for the purpose of clarity.

Comment: +1, nice answer. I will have a look at this for one of my tasks. One little mistake though. You got `$arr[2]` and `$arr[3]` with the wrong index

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute the query for different array value.... So you need to have a function which accept array variable, and then execute all the array items in this query right!.

```
 function result_table($arr_var){
      $sizeof_arr = sizeof($arr_var);
      if($sizeof_arr == 3){
         foreach ($arr_var as $val)
        {
           $qry_array[] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column 1 = $val[0] AND column 2 !=    $val[2] AND column 3 > $val[3]";

           return $qry_array;
        }
      }else{
           echo "Array values number is wrong";
      }

 }

 $arr_val = array((3,35,10), array (9,12,293), array(6, 96, 39));
 $union_qry = result_table($arr_val);
```

Comment: This will only accept 3 triples, though MKK presumably wants to support an arbitrary number of tuples. Furthermore, it will return an array with only the first generated statement.

Comment: @outis, i only give the idea, but this can be further enhance... i.e. dynamic parameters...

Comment: it's not a matter of enhancement. The sample code is incorrect.

Comment: won't this not work?-- the foreach loop will return before its gon through all of arr_var?

Comment: @babonk: my point exactly. (Note: double negatives lack clarity in English. "Won't this fail" is a better phrasing than "won't this not work".)

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll need to prevent SQL injection, you'd do well to use a prepared statement.

If `$_POST` contains arrays of triples:

```
# sample data
$_POST = array(array(3,35,10), array(9,12,293), array(6, 96, 39));

# utility functions
function array_flatten_into($source, &$target) {
    foreach ($source as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            array_flatten_into($val, $target);
        } else {
            $target[] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $target;
}
function array_flatten($arr) {
    $flat = array();
    return array_flatten_into($arr, $flat);
}

# create the query
$statement = 'SELECT ... FROM table WHERE ' 
             . implode(' OR ', 
                       array_fill(0, count($_POST), '(col1 = ? AND col2 != ? AND col3 > ?)'));
$query = $db->prepare($statement);
$query->execute(array_flatten($_POST));
```

If `$_POST` is a flat array:

```
$_POST = array(3,35,10, 9,12,293, 6, 96, 39);

$statement = 'SELECT ... FROM table WHERE ' 
             . implode(' OR ', 
                       array_fill(0, count($_POST)/3, '(col1 = ? AND col2 != ? AND col3 > ?)'));
$query = $db->prepare($statement);
# call to `array_values` isn't necessary in this particular example, but may be
# in the actual code if $_POST is sparse or has non-integer keys
$query->execute(array_values($_POST));
```

Once you have more than 1 triple, performance will degrade as MySQL will need to run a table scan.

Comment: Since the MySQL query is hard coded and the variables are only integers, it should be good enough (I think) to make sure all the values in the array are integers (if_numeric) and if not then I kill the script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look into prepared statements. You can use [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) 
. Here when you are running the same query over and over again, the query will be compiled when executed first time and we can bind the values many time.